# L.esri.Cluster.featureLayer does not call style function

Tags: leaflet, clustering, esri-leaflet

Using the `L.esri.Cluster.featureLayer` plugin for Leaflet to cluster features from Esri does not call the `style` method despite the documentation stating that this is the way to style vector layers.

Docs: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/cluster-feature-layer.html

Options has a `style` method like the one for vanilla Leaflet feature layers. L.esri.featureLayer does use the `style` option properly, but the cluster version does not appear to be doing this - or I am doing something wrong.

Sample code:

```
var bikePaths = L.esri.Cluster.featureLayer({
    url: 'https://services.arcgis.com/uCXeTVveQzP4IIcx/ArcGIS/rest/services/Bike_Routes/FeatureServer/0',
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer)
    {
        // this works - called for each feature
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng)
    {
        // this works - called for each point feature
    },
    style: function (feature, layer)
    {
        // never called - despite having linear and polygon features
        // the linear and polygon features do show up fine.
        // they don't cluster, but that's to be expected (they are vectors)
        // wth documentation?
    },
  }).addTo(map)
```

Anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Also reported to the plugin maintainers on GitHub: https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-cluster/issues/23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing and debugging I concluded this is a bug in either the docs or the plugin (or both). It seems to be caused by the asynchronous nature of loading Esri feature layers.

My work-around solution is to manually call `resetStyle` for vector features from within `onEachFeature` so that I can apply a custom initial style to the polygon and line features.

To wit:

```
var bikePaths = L.esri.Cluster.featureLayer({
    url: 'https://services.arcgis.com/uCXeTVveQzP4IIcx/ArcGIS/rest/services/Bike_Routes/FeatureServer/0',
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer)
    {
        if (feature.geometry.type !== "Point" && feature.geometry.type !== "MultiPoint") 
        {
            // explicit call to resetStyle, now that we have feature data
            bikePaths.resetStyle(feature.id);
        }
    },
    style: function (feature, layer)
    {                        
        // do different styling magic based on feature properties and return style object
        return { color: "pink", weight: 5, opacity: 50 };
    },
  }).addTo(map)
```

Good enough - shipped it!